# DatePickerDialog is not persisting String/crashing

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I have modified a TimePicker I found here to use DatePicker instead. The TimePicker works flawlessly in storing the milliseconds in long format for the specified time, however, changing to SimpleDateFormat and storing a String is becoming quite errorous.

Here is my code,

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DateSelector extends DialogPreference
{
    private Calendar calendar;
    private android.widget.DatePicker picker = null;

    public DateSelector(Context ctxt) {
        this(ctxt, null);
    }
    public DateSelector(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(ctxt, attrs, android.R.attr.dialogPreferenceStyle);
    }
    public DateSelector(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(ctxt, attrs, defStyle);
        setPositiveButtonText("Save");
        setNegativeButtonText("Cancel");
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    }
    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        picker = new android.widget.DatePicker(getContext());
        return (picker);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View v) {
        super.onBindDialogView(v);
        picker.updateDate(
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

        if (positiveResult)
        {
            updateCalendar( picker.getDayOfMonth(), picker.getMonth(), picker.getYear() );

            setSummary(getSummary());

            if (callChangeListener(calendar.getTimeInMillis() )) {
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
                //persistString(format.format(calendar.getTime() );
                notifyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
        return (a.getString(index));
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue)
    {
        if (restoreValue)
        {
            if (defaultValue == null) {
                updateCalendar(
                        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            } else {
                String[] split = defaultValue.toString().split("-");
                updateCalendar(
                        Integer.parseInt(split[1]), Integer.parseInt(split[0]), Integer.parseInt(split[2]));
            }
        } else {
            if (defaultValue == null) {
                updateCalendar(
                        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            } else {
                String[] split = defaultValue.toString().split("-");
                updateCalendar(
                        Integer.parseInt(split[1]), Integer.parseInt(split[0]), Integer.parseInt(split[2]));
            }
        }
        setSummary(getSummary());
    }
    public void updateCalendar( int day, int month, int year ) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day );
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month );
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getSummary() {
        if (calendar != null) {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
            return format.format(calendar.getTime());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

For the life of me, I can not getting it work as it crashes on the persistString method. I am under the impression I am using this correctly. Is there anyone with some wisdom on the subject?

Here is my logcat:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String
>                                                                                     at
>   android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:224)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.preference.Preference.getPersistedString(Preference.java:1429)
>                                                                                     at android.preference.Preference.persistString(Preference.java:1398)

Which I'm sure why it is giving this as I am trying to store a string.

Here is also the Preferences Screen,

```
    <Utilities.DateSelector
        android:title="Year / Month / Day "
        android:key="date"
        android:dependency="birthday"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Rusheel I updated the main post.

Comment: where exactly are you getting the error. Can you please highlight the code.

Comment: The code you shared doesn't have any preferences code but your logs state that there is something to do with preferences.Please paste relevant code and also latest crash logs.

Comment: Updated again, sorry for the confusion! The commented line seems to be the problem area.

Comment: persistString() is your own method right? Mind posting it, as that is where the error is actually.

Comment: No it's an Android function.

Comment: Strangest question I had ever seen! I tried your code and in my case code is working fine. Not only that, the error you said `java.lang.ClassCastException` is kind of impossible to occur. Because, it is sort of impossible to occur on the line (persistString) you mentioned. SimpleDateFormat.format() is also working fine. Let me know if you found solution of this problem. I am curious to know. :)

Comment: You were absolutely right Dave, I reinstalled Android studio and the issue was magically resolved. How strange.. Thanks for the time to comment and lead me the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the method expects a String but you are handing it a long. Try this:

```
persistString("" + format.format(calendar.getTime() );
```

That line of code will convert the long value into a String.

Comment: This definitely will not work. format() returns a string, and persistString() takes a String. No dice, sir. The "" changes nothing.